# Displaying errors on a macOS app with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to display errors or things that didn't go quite according to plan on a macOS Big Sur app.

For example, I have a function that will open the directory where the files the application saves are locates, however there are cases where this fails to work, due to the URL being empty, or other errors, and I can't figure out how to showcase that to the user. This function is the following:

```
func showInFinder(url: URL?) {
    guard let url = url else {
        print("returning... URL nil ")
        return
    }
    NSWorkspace.shared.selectFile(nil, inFileViewerRootedAtPath: url.path)
}
```

I was thinking on displaying an alert, like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showsAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showsAlert.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: self.$showsAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Hello"))
        }
    }
}
```

But in most places where I need the error to be displayed is on functions, not views. Unless I can display them on the buttons being pressed, or on actions like `onAppear()`.

Any suggestions? Specifically for functions.

Comment: `.alert` is only for SwiftUI Views it will not work in a function or attached to a function. You can use `.alert(item:)` to send a custom object  with the information needed for the alert such as the title and the message to a shared view model so the alert is presented with the custom message. `.alert` is a view modifier it needs a `View`.

Comment: So, essentially I need to review the return of a function (bool, int, etc) and decide of something went wrong, then display the alert? Can I have more than one alert per view?

Comment: Yes you need to assess and no you can't have more than one alert because they present in the same spot and you will have bugs. Like I said `alert(item)` will let you use a custom object like a `struct` that should have a `title` and `message` variable with the custom information.